# What is "HTML1114" error in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I send a GET request to the oembedly server. The response is

```
{
    "provider_url": "https://developer.mozilla.org",
    "description": "Apply a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) as to reduce it to a single value.",
    "title": "Array reduce method",
    "dominant_colors": [{
        "color": [19, 13, 12],
        "weight": 0.507080078125
    }, {
        "color": [219, 48, 41],
        "weight": 0.345458984375
    }, {
        "color": [240, 240, 240],
        "weight": 0.1474609375
    }],
    "thumbnail_width": 62,
    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png",
    "entropy": 2.00440402346,
    "version": "1.0",
    "provider_name": "Mozilla",
    "type": "link",
    "thumbnail_height": 71
}
```

A normal JSON response as far as I can see. But the success handler is not called, and I get

```
HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (11)
```

that message on the console.

I'm running IE9, with Browser Mode: IE8, Document Mode: IE8 Standards.

Please put me out of my misery...

Comment: check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/is/web/thread/2b7be95a-a90b-425f-b799-1b68a6d94f77

Comment: can you remove the BOM ( byte order mark ) at the header of the response? IE does not support this.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I will do anything. But how do I do what you just said??